# HttpListenerRequest.GetClientCertificate() not returning the complete certificate chain

Tags: c#, httplistener, httplistenerrequest

I have a web server implemented using [HttpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=net-6.0) in C#, there is a Go client which talks to this server. As part of the requirement I need to validate the certificates sent from the client on the server and I'm sending a certificate chain from the client. I found the method [HttpListenerRequest.GetClientCertificate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerrequest.getclientcertificate?view=net-6.0) to get the certificates on the server but I am able to receive only the leaf certificate but not the entire chain which is blocking me to perform the chain validation. Is there a way to receive the entire chain using HttpListener as the server.

PS: I tried sending the same certificate chain to a Go server and Go has ssl callback handler(*VerifyPeerCertificate*) in [Tls Config](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config) using which I am able to read the entire certificate chain. I just want to acheive this with the existing HttpListener server I have in C#.

**Edit:** My client certificate is a chain (client cert + Intermediate CA + Root CA). I have the Root CA pre stored in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities. I need to get the Intermediate CA in the Windows Trust Store so that I can build the chain for the client certificate and as I can't pre store the Intermediate CA the idea is to send the chain from the client and extract the Intermediate CA when the client talks to the server.
As I am able to receive the complete chain using a Go server with the same client I can confirm that client sends the chain always but somehow the methods we have in C# for `HttpListener` seems to ignore the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the client is just sending its client certificate, then it is the server responsibility to check that the client certificate is trusted. If anyone can send a client certificate with the complete chain, then the server can accept any certification authority (including any compromised). So the certificate of the certification authority that has emitted the client certificate must be trusted on the server to ensure this authority is trusted and the server can request this authority to ensure the client certificate has not been revoked. On Windows this is done by adding the certificate of the certification authority to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.

The `HttpListenerRequest.GetClientCertificate()` [source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System/net/System/Net/HttpListenerRequest.cs) loads just one certificate.

It's on the server side to check the complete chain. The server must be able to connect to the AIA that has signed the client certificate to download the intermediate CA.

```
            var chain = new X509Chain();
            chain.ChainPolicy = new X509ChainPolicy()
            {
                DisableCertificateDownloads = false,
                RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain,
                RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online,
                UrlRetrievalTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero,
                VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags
            };
```

You may try to implement your own `HttpListenerRequest` and use it as a middleware in the pipeline.

Comment: The cert chain contains cert + intermediate CA + root CA. I pre stored the rootCA in Trusted Root Certification Authorities store but I still need the intermediate CA(signer of the cert) to verify the chain on server and I can't pre store it because it isn't available before my server start. So the idea is to get the intermediate CA when the client contacts the server and store it in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.

Comment: Intermediate Certification Authorities is the best store for Intermediate CA. When the server start you can still programmatically add the intermediate CA to the store so that it become available. Another option may be to use `X509Chain` and `X509ChainPolicy`. The `X509Chain` has `Build()` method to verify the certificate and maybe have more information. Are you sure the client certificate provide enough information (Authority Information Access) and that the server can contact any endpoint of the authority?

Comment: How do I add the intermediate CA cert without having the cert at the server start time ? I tried the `X509Chain.Build()` on the certificate I received through `HttpListenerRequest.GetClientCertificate()` and accessed the certificates in the chain through below code but I can only see the leaf certificate and chain building fails with partial chain formed as I don't have the intermediate CA cert in the trust store.
 `foreach (var chainElement in chain.ChainElements)
 {
       var certInChain = chainElement.Certificate;
}`
I am sure that client certificate has the complete chain.

Comment: Because the server is unable to retrieve "online" the intermediate server from AIA endpoints defined on the client certificate. But seriously an intermediate CA that wouldn't be available before the server starts ... that means the intermediate CA is really ephemeral or hosted on the fly on the server.

Comment: Firstly thanks for pointing out a way to download the cert chain from the server. Unfortunately, none of the certificates in client chain have AIA tag so I can't use the method you have suggested.

Comment: This is problematic if the client certificate doesn't have the AIA extension. I don't know why the client certificate template doesn't provide this extension but this would definitely help you more than developing your own `GetClientCertificate()` substitute. It's even not sure this would work.

Comment: That's true and I don't have time to try implementing own `GetClientCertificate()` as I'm struck with a deadline. I was looking if I can set some callback like [RemoteCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback?view=net-6.0) on the server to see if I can retrieve the chain.

Comment: Yes you can but same issue, either you fully trust the client certificate without any validation which is not a good point for security reasons, either you're stuck with the intermediate CA not being available (in the server trust store and/or using AIA). Personally I can't help more.

Comment: No issues, thanks for all the help you have provided.